# How can I use Autofac in .NET core console generic host?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dependency-injection, autofac

I have .NET core console application using generic host. I have worker class (ImageFileWatcher) and additional class(ThumbnailProcessor) with it's interface (IThumbnailProcessor). I want to use Autofac implementation for dependency injection instead of usual implementation of DI. How can I do this? Here is my program.cs code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext,configBuilder) =>
            {
                configBuilder.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "ImageService_");
            })
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<ImageFileWatcher>();

                services.AddSingleton<IThumbnailProcessor, ThumbnailProcessor>();

                var config = hostContext.Configuration;

                services.AddOptions<ImageConfig>()
                    .Configure(imageConfig =>
                    {
                        imageConfig.CompressionLevel = 0.99M;
                    })
                    .Bind(config.GetSection(nameof(ImageConfig)));

                services.AddOptions<ImageSizeConfig>(ImageSizeConfig.Thumbnail)
                    .Configure(thumbnailSizeConfig =>
                    {
                        thumbnailSizeConfig.FilePrefix = "thumb-";
                    })
                    .Bind(config.GetSection("ImageConfig:thumbnail"));

                services.Configure<ImageSizeConfig>(ImageSizeConfig.Medium, config.GetSection("ImageConfig:medium"));
                services.Configure<ImageSizeConfig>(ImageSizeConfig.Large, config.GetSection("ImageConfig:large"));

            });

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Install `Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection`
2. Add this call to the process of building the host -> `.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())`
3. Add `ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(...)` to the process of building the host and define your dependencies

There is [a sample for this as well](https://github.com/autofac/Examples/tree/master/src/GenericHostBuilderExample).